# How do I have a domain redirect to a subfolder of a different domain's hosting to read an .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns

Here's the scenario:

I have DomainA and DomainB.  DomainA has no hosting and DomainB has hosting.

I want to direct DomainA to a subfolder of DomainB's hosting where an .htaccess file lies.  This .htaccess file contains a bunch of 301 redirect rules for DomainA.

Is this possible and will this successfully keep DomainA's 301 redirect rules in place?

Edit: The redirect rules for DomainA are redirecting URLS from DomainA to urls on DomainB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make website on DomainB respond to requests for DomainA. Then

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} DomainA
RewriteRule (.*) DomainB/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'm not sure if query string is kept on redirect, but that can be fixed.

Comment: Is there anyway to do it without access to Apache configs?  I also should have mentioned: the redirect rules in place for DomainA are actually redirecting DomainA to urls on DomainB.  Not sure if that changes anything...

Comment: @TimJahn sorry, I got it all wrong, I mistakenly read that DomainB doesn't have hosting and A has. What do you mean it doesn't have hosting? Try "host DomainA" - does it point to your server? Do you get any response when issuing an HTTP Request to DomainA?

Comment: DomainA currently has hosting but I'd like to get rid of it since the hosting is simply hosting an .htaccess file now to maintain the 301 redirects (which redirect to DomainB).  Since DomainB has hosting (it's an actual site with files, etc.), I figured why not host the DomainA .htaccess within a folder on DomainB's hosting and simply point DomainA there.

I just wasn't sure if the 301 redirects will remain in tact.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you can make the website in DomainB respond to requests for DomainA, then this is solved - it depends on the type of hosting you have. Maybe park DomainA, or set it as an alias for DomainB. I'll edit my answer to show you the rewrites you need to set in .htaccess

Comment: What are some ways to make the website in DomainB respond to requests for DomainA?

Comment: DNS must be set to the same machine (same IP for DomainA as it is for DomainB). Then, it depends on the web server config. If you have a virtual host, then the sys admin must set your DomainA as ServerAlias for DomainB.